# YouTubeBaseActivity in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-jetpack-compose, android-youtube-api

I want to use YouTube player from `YouTubeDataAPI v3` in Jetpack Compose. But it should be extended of `YouTubeBaseActivity`. The main problem is that activity extended of `YouTubeBaseActivity` haven't composable `setContent { }`. Only `setContentView()`. Should i create another activity, extended of `YouTubeBaseActivity` and xml layout? Or there is another way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YouTubeBaseActivity` extends the base `Activity` directly, which do not implement proper extension function. But you can work around that by using `YouTubePlayerFragment`. The first thing [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) is mentioning is that while using this fragment you don't have to extend your activity from `YouTubeBaseActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can create compose view manually. Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments) shows how to do it with a fragment, but you can do the same with an activity - subclass it from `YouTubeBaseActivity`, add this to your XML view:

```xml
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then you can set compose content to this view.